# Perl greedy regex is not acting greedy

Tags: regex, perl

Giving the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "asdf(blablabla)";

$text =~ s/(.*?)\((.*)\)/$2/;
print "\nfirst match: $1";
print "\nsecond match: $2";
```

I expected that `$2` would catch my last bracket, yet my output is:
[image]

If `.*` by default it's greedy why it stopped at the bracket?

Comment: You actually defined it in the pattern: `)` (matched with `\)`) must be outside Group 2.

Comment: `.*?` is **lazy** !

Comment: @Jan you are missunderstanding my question, i was talking about the second `.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` is a greedy subpattern, but it does not account for grouping. Grouping is defined with a pair of unescaped parentheses (see [*Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)).

See where your group boundaries are:

```
s/(.*?)\((.*)\)/$2/
  | G1|  |G2|
```

So, the `\(` and `\)` matching `(` and `)` are *outside the groups*, and will not be part of neither `$1` nor `$2`.

If you need the `)` be part of `$2`, use

```
s/(.*?)\((.*\))/$2/
              ^
```

A regex engine is processing both the string and the pattern from left to right. The first `(.*?)` is handled first, and it matches up to the first literal `(` symbol as it is lazy (matches as few chars as possible before it can return a valid match), and the whole part before the `(` is placed into Group 1 stack. Then, the `(` is matched, but not captured, then `(.*)` matches any 0+ characters other than a newline up to the last `)` symbol, and places the capture into Group 2. Then, the `)` is just matched. The point is that `.*` grabs the whole string up to the end, but then backtracking happens since the engine tries to accommodate for the final `)` in the pattern. The `)` must be matched, but not captured in your pattern, thus, it is not part of Group 2 due to the group boundary placement. You can see the *regex debugger* at [this regex demo page](https://regex101.com/r/xS9dJ8/1) to see how the pattern matches your string.

Comment: Corect me if i wrong, so when searching for a pattern, it will first try to find the "things" outside of the groupings and then search in the text delimited by the outside rules?

Comment: In this case, it searched for the brackets, found them, and then searched for `.*` in the text between the brackets, is that right?

Comment: It is not right. I added the explanation to the answer.